# Wrap static function (IIFE) into prototype

Tags: javascript, class, iife

I wrote a function that I thought I'd only need to process 1 object but it turns out I need more than 1.  I will use a simple example:

```
var Helper = (function () {
    return {
        el: null
        init: function(el) {
            this.el = el;
        }
        doStuff: function(){
            // Modify this.el in someway
        }
    };
}());
```

So then I'd just do `Helper.init(el)` on page load and then run `Helper.doStuff()` when I needed it.

Well now I have three elements who need this functionality.

My first idea was to just make it do  `Helper.init([el1,el2,el3])`  and have it work on an array of elements but I may want to treat each element separately.

I am thinking the best approach is to probably turn the Helper IIFE into a "class" with prototype, but I am a bit crunch on time so I was looking for a way to make a wrapper to accomplish what I need.

I was thinking I can just take the function and not immediately execute it, and then somehow store that function into a prototyped function and utilize it that way.

Looking for ideas on how to best do this with minimal code change.

Comment: Was there a reason for the IIFE in the first place? In your example, you could just assign the object to `Helper`.

Comment: *"I am thinking the best approach is to probably turn the Helper IIFE into a "class" with prototype, but I am a bit crunch on time..."* I wouldn't expect it to take very long. Probably less than writing the question? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am thinking the best approach is to probably turn the Helper IIFE into a "class" with prototype, but I am a bit crunch on time...

I wouldn't expect it to take very long.

> I was thinking I can just take the function and not immediately execute it, and then somehow store that function into a prototyped function and utilize it that way.
>
> Looking for ideas on how to best do this with minimal code change.

The class pattern is just one pattern in JavaScript, you can use that `Helper` just like it is as the prototype of other objects, which matches your "minimal changes" requirement. Just use `Object.create`:

```
var helper1 = Object.create(Helper);
helper1.init(el);
var helper2 = Object.create(Helper);
helper2.init(el2);
var helper3 = Object.create(Helper);
helper3.init(el3);

// ...
helper1.doStuff();
helper2.doStuff();
helper3.doStuff();
```

If you add `return this;` to the end of `init`, that can be more concise:

```
var helper1 = Object.create(Helper).init(el);
var helper2 = Object.create(Helper).init(el2);
var helper3 = Object.create(Helper).init(el3);

// ...
helper1.doStuff();
helper2.doStuff();
helper3.doStuff();
```

Live Example:

```js
var Helper = (function () {
    return {
        el: null,
        init: function(el) {
            this.el = el;
            return this;
        },
        doStuff: function(){
            this.el.style.color = "green";
            this.el.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        }
    };
}());
var helper1 = Object.create(Helper).init(document.getElementById("el1"));
var helper2 = Object.create(Helper).init(document.getElementById("el2"));
var helper3 = Object.create(Helper).init(document.getElementById("el3"));

// ...
setTimeout(function() {
  helper1.doStuff();
}, 400);
setTimeout(function() {
  helper2.doStuff();
}, 800);
setTimeout(function() {
  helper3.doStuff();
}, 1200);
```

```html
<div id="el1">el1</div>
<div id="el2">el2</div>
<div id="el3">el3</div>
```

You could even keep using `Helper` directly on the first `el`, further reducing code changes, though I wouldn't recommend it.

---

Alternately, wrap it in a function that returns it (and here I've also included that change to `init`):

```
function getHelper() {
    var Helper = (function () {
        return {
            el: null,
            init: function(el) {
                this.el = el;
                return this; // <============== Added
            },
            doStuff: function(){
                // Modify this.el in someway
            }
        };
    }());
    return Helper;
}
```

Then for your three places you need it:

```
var helper1 = getHelper().init(el);
var helper2 = getHelper().init(el2);
var helper3 = getHelper().init(el2);

// ...
helper1.doStuff();
helper2.doStuff();
helper3.doStuff();
```

---

Side note: You don't need the IIFE there anyway unless you have things in it that aren't shown beyond the object initializer...

Answer (score -1):

Just rewritten code:

```
function Helper (el) {
    this.el = el;
}
Helper.prototype = {        
    doStuff: function(){
            // Modify this.el in someway
    }
};

var helper1 = new Helper(el1);
var helper2 = new Helper(el2);
var helper3 = new Helper(el3);

helper1.doStaff();
helper2.doStaff();
helper3.doStaff();
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way, retrieves arguments from `arguments` object:

```
var Helper = (function () {
    return {
        el: null
        init: function() {
            this.el = Array.from(arguments)
        }
        doStuff: function(){
            this.el.forEach(el => {
                // Modify el in someway
            });
        }
    };
}());
```